# Как записать PHP массив в файл и считать его из файла

Tags: php, массивы, запись

```html
<?php

$bookshelf = array(
  array(
    array(
      'author' => 'Л. Толстый',
      'title' => 'Война и пир',
      'year' => 2005,
    ),
    array(
      'author' => 'Н. Гоголь-Моголь',
      'title' => 'Мертвые уши',
      'year' => 2005,
    ),
  ),
  array(
    array(
      'author' => 'Г. Велс',
      'title' => 'Машина Бремени',
      'year' => 2009,
    ),
    array(
      'author' => 'Э. Дерроуз',
      'title' => 'Нарзан',
      'year' => 1994,
    ),
  ),
);

$bookshelf[] = 'SuperPuper';
object2file($bookshelf, 'array.txt');
```

Нужно выполнить запись в файл и чтение из файла этого массива, я только учусь.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$filename = 'array.txt';

// Запись.
$data = serialize($bookshelf);      // PHP формат сохраняемого значения.
//$data = json_encode($bookshelf);  // JSON формат сохраняемого значения.
file_put_contents($filename, $data);

// Чтение.
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
//$bookshelf = json_decode($data, TRUE); // Если нет TRUE то получает объект, а не массив.
$bookshelf = unserialize($data);
```

Comment: `json_encode`/`json_decode` для лучшей совместимости?

Comment: @E_p, спасибо за дополнение. Выбор между `serialize()` и `json_encode()` зависит от многих факторов, но `serialize()` более роднее для PHP.

Comment: Если массив "большой", например, занимает в памяти 20M, и у PHP в конфиге стоит ограничение на объем используемой памяти, например, 32M, то промежуточная переменная $data может вызвать ошибку 500. Было бы интересно решение без $data.

Comment: @Руслан, да, но перед этим нужно все равно сериализовать данные. От ситуации с файлом особо не отличается. Postgres или SQLite, по крайней мере, на уровне C API предоставляют что-то типа дескрипторов файлов для BLOB-полей.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov вы правы, я облажался...

Comment: @Руслан, если массив хранится в реляционной БД и разложен по реляциям, то правы вы. Не известно, что именно было нужно автору вопроса.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov я затупил, что не увидел как он " $bookshelf[] = 'SuperPuper';
object2file($bookshelf, 'array.txt'); " пытался записать это в файл. я думал он вручную хотел записать массив и открыть)))