# Как узнать, какие параметры GET запроса приходят на сервер?

Tags: php, get

Сервер принимает get запрос вида: https://example.com/test.php?....
Как узнать, какие параметры приходят на сервер, если клиент в этом не участвует?

Comment: `print_r($_GET)`?

Comment: @u_mulder клиент не участвует в этом, это происходит между двумя серверами,  http уведомление, мне нужно может в файл записать get запрос или что-то вроде того

Comment: Что значит "клиент не участвует"?

Comment: @u_mulder у меня яндекс касса отправляет get запрос на ссылку, которую я укажу. На эту страницу приходит get запрос, но проблема в том, что я не знаю, какие там параметры передаются, я нигде не нашел, поэтому я хочу узнать, какие параметры от яндекса приходят.

Comment: Ну запиши массив `$_GET` в файл.

Comment: @u_mulder я пытался, но не получилось, постоянные ошибки. Я недавно начал изучать php, и не особо понимаю, какие функции надо использовать(((

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656848/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-php-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0

Comment: @u_mulder спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file_put_contents('get-' . time() . '.txt', json_encode($_GET));
```

При каждом обращении все get параметры будут записаны в файл. Лучше такое повторить и с $_POST параметрами